# Index must be within the bounds of the List - C# error

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error when attempting to insert into a list. I'm trying to insert into the start of the list using

```
myList.Insert(myValue, 0);
```

The weird thing is, when the debugger comes up, myList has a Count of 1. So 0 is within the bounds of the list. So why would I get this exception?

Comment: shouldn't it be [`.Insert(0, myValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `Insert` Is

```
public void Insert(int index, T item)
```

so your arguments are reversed.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of [`List.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the index and the second  is the value that you insert.

So this should work as expected:

```
myList.Insert(0, myValue);
```

By the way, it works even if the list was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is your problem but I think that List.Insert definition is

```
public void Insert(int index, T item)
```

So with your code, your "myValue" is actually the index that List will use to insert in your List and "0" is your value.

Hopes that will help you !